# SharePoint Framework Modern apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-store

Are there currently any downloadable SPFX Apps in the store for Free or Purchase?
 Are Developers currently able to publish and sell their Modern Apps using SPFX? What are Microsoft's plans for the shift in technology in the Marketplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, the Office Store doesn't support SharePoint Framework solutions. So far, there haven't been any announcements regarding publishing SharePoint Framework solutions through the Office Store.